# How to replace all words so that it is inside double quote?

Tags: java, json

I have a below json string

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "task_id": ["000JAGUAR8M,000JAGUAR94,000JAG0009I,000JQQ0009O,000JAGUAR6Y,000JAGUAR7H,000JAGUAR7I,000JAKAAL7J,000BAKAAL7K,000JAGUAR7L"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "task_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "task_id",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to replace only `task_id` part inside terms so that each task is inside a double quote.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "task_id": ["000JAGUAR8M","000JAGUAR94","000JAG0009I","000JQQ0009O","000JAGUAR6Y","000JAGUAR7H","000JAGUAR7I","000JAKAAL7J","000BAKAAL7K","000JAGUAR7L"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "task_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "task_id",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to read the task_ids using below code, but how can I write back the changed value (`requiredTasksIdValues`) in the json object?

```
String str = "{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"terms\":{\"task_id\":[\"000JAGUAR8M,000JAGUAR94,000JAG0009I,000JQQ0009O,000JAGUAR6Y,000JAGUAR7H,000JAGUAR7I,000JAKAAL7J,000BAKAAL7K,000JAGUAR7L\"]}}]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"task_ids\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"task_id\",\"size\":0}}}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    JsonNode taskIdsjsonNode = mapper.readTree(str);
    JsonNode jn = taskIdsjsonNode.get("query").get("filtered").get("filter").get("bool").get("must").get(0).get("terms").get("task_id");
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(jn.toString().substring(2));
    temp = new StringBuffer(temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 2));
    String[] temp_task_ids = temp.toString().split(",");            
    StringBuffer requiredTasksIdValues = new StringBuffer();
    for (String taskid: temp_task_ids) {
        requiredTasksIdValues.append("\""+taskid+"\",");
    }
    requiredTasksIdValues = new StringBuffer(requiredTasksIdValues.substring(0, requiredTasksIdValues.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(requiredTasksIdValues);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: that is comma separated string, can you split it with comma and then assign to `task_id`. It will be an array then which is what you looking for

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Do you know how to parse the JSON? If so, strip that part from your question as it's irrelevant. If you don't know how to parse it, go research that and let us know where you got stuck.

Comment: Why not just find and replace `,000` to `","000`?

Comment: @Duncan: I need to prepare this query in such way that each task_id is under a double quote

Comment: @Ricky Right... so you have a JSON string and you want to edit it? Do you know how to parse the string so that you can edit bits of it?

Comment: @Sippy: I was thinking something like `str = str.replaceAll("(?>\"task_id\":\\[)([\\w\\d]+)", "");` to identify using `"task_id":["` and then replace all [\w\d]+ with `"[\w\d]+"`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Duncan: Is it possible to parse json without using any third party library or I can use jackson?

Comment: @Ricky I'm guessing from that response, you don't currently know how to parse the JSON. **Please go research that first, it's easily done.** Come back and edit your question once you've solved that (or hit a problem).

Comment: @Duncan: I have parsed json and prepared data which needs to be replaced, but now how do I modify the existing json query?

Answer (score 1):

```
String original = "000JAGUAR8M,000JAGUAR94,000JAG0009I,000JQQ0009O,000JAGUAR6Y,000JAGUAR7H,000JAGUAR7I,000JAKAAL7J,000BAKAAL7K,000JAGUAR7L";

String[] elements = original.split(",");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
```